# Chat message disappears after edit and reload on mobile

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-safari

On mobile chat, a message disappears (only on mobile, apparently still visible on desktop) when you edit it, and while editing, reload the page. Is this intended? If so, why?

Steps to reproduce AFAIK:

- Use Safari on iOS 10.1.1
- Mobile chat on StackExchange

  1. Send a message
  2. Click on the pencil to edit it
  3. While editing, reload the page

The sent message will not appear on mobile iOS Safari, but will appear on Desktop. No other browsers have been tested.

**Note**: This only happens *periodically*. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not.